# PyQt5 (Qt5.2.1) Installation - Can't import QtWebkitIems

Tags: qt, qtwebkit, pyqt5

I've installed Qt5.2.1 / SIP 4.5.15 and PyQt5 on my Ubuntu 12.4 desktop. Everything seemed OK until I try to import **QtWebKitWidgets**. This module is very important in my code.

```
>>> from PyQt5 import QtWebkitWidgets
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name QtWebkitItems
>>>
```

No error raised during the installation phase. in my **/opt/Qt5.2.1/5.2.1/gcc_64/lib** directory I can see the corresponding Qt libs.

Does anyone have an idea ?

Thank you in advance

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where you're getting "QtWebkitItems" from (a web-search gets no hits other than this page), but the real problem is a simple typo. The import statement should be:

```
    from PyQt5 import QtWebKitWidgets # upper-case K!
```

PS: it's nicely ironic that you managed to spell it right in your question, and even highlighted it in bold!

Comment: Oppps was tired. Thanks a lot